# Can anyone explain the method of changing the colour of border of a checkbox ?

Tags: android-layout

Because I  already  searched various places but i did not get proper solution.
By both methods 
1)By using **style theme**
2)By using **shape file**
whenever i used **style theme** method to change the border(in class **extends** **Activity class**),it gives base.theme related error and and said to change the extend class  to **AppCompatActivity** but it does not work with immersive mode.